# Export file with utf 8 for non-english characters in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

This part of code puts the `EΞ` characters in a column and when exported it shows `??` in their place.

```
import geopandas 

dff['KAEK']=dff['CAD'].str[:5].add('ΕΞ').add(dff['CAD_AD_F'].str[5:]).add(dff['rank'])
dff.to_file(out)
```

Where can i set the `utf-8`?

Comment: "It shows" is probably the part which is wrong.  What are you using to examine the output file, and is that tool properly able and correctly configured to handle UTF-8?

Comment: @Rakesh No, this is about the result from the code, not about the encoding of the Python script.

Comment: I think encoding during export is important for other software that read the result to be able to read it as it should.I also tried `dff.to_file(out,encoding='utf-8)` but simply replaced the ?? with incomprehersible characters

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that a different encoding worked. Just use `dff. to_file(out,encoding='')`and where is the encoding try your language specific versions until you find it.